# What is the best way to maintain a redacted replica of my MongoDB for analytical and investigation purposes?

Tags: mongodb, etl

I have a production dataset in my MongoDB which I use to run my application, I would like to give my devs access to the data in this database but the database contains sensitive data which I don't want exposed to devs poking around in the database. I would also prefer that the devs don't have access directly to the prod database, but rather have access to a replica of it stored somewhere else.

Ideally, I would prefer to use some tool to maintain a perfect replica of my MongoDB database in another MongoDB database, however, with the replica being redacted so no sensitive data is present.

As a plus, it would be nice if the data could also be transformed and aggregated in different ways before it lands in the second database.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a change stream. In the change stream listener, redact the new/updated documents and write them to the analytics instance.